# Chart.js - Same min and max value of two charts

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

[image]

I have a simple question:

How can i align this two chartjs charts so to have exact the same grid?

The two charts have same min and max value, furthermore there is a missmatch because in the first chart the y tick labels are letters so the widthes of y axis are different.

Any advice would be usefull,

Chris Pappas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no nice way of doing this. The only dirty workaround I could think of is putting a whole lot of spaces before the tick in the callback from the chart which has to be indented more:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          callback: (val) => (`                ${val}`)
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js" integrity="sha512-hZf9Qhp3rlDJBvAKvmiG+goaaKRZA6LKUO35oK6EsM0/kjPK32Yw7URqrq3Q+Nvbbt8Usss+IekL7CRn83dYmw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```